# Why getItem(position) works with a new instance? (should not be zero?)

Tags: java, android, casting, android-listfragment

I'm trying learn java, I read about casting, Instantiate Objects, Arrays, HashMaps, etc.
I was making codes for Android and I was doing well until I found myself with this:

```
MyObject instObject = (MyObject)getItem(position);
```

From what I've learned so far... I'm creating a new instance of MyObject in instObject, so, I think that the value should be zero.
But then, when I call `setText(...)`, it works!  =o

Please try not to summarize the answer because understand this has been very difficult to me so far!
I speak Spanish, I know a little English but not so well.

```
public class MyClass extends ListFragment {
    List<MyObject> instObject;  //instObject = 0
    ...

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        instObject = new ArrayList<MyObject>();
        MyObject item = ...
        instObject.add(item); //instObject = items
    }

    //Adapter{
        ...

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
            MyObject instObject = (MyObject)getItem(position);
            //instObject = ? (should not be zero?)
            holder.title.setText( instObject.getTitle() );
            // why return the corresponding title?
        }  
    }

    public class MyObject {  
        vars...  
        constructor...  
        setters...  
        getters...  
    }
}
```

**Solved THANKS!!! :)**

I had three confusions...

**First:**
I thought that if "instObject", was created inside of "onActivityCreated", this "instObject", could no be accessed from inside the adapter. (and we can't)
Inside of adapter, "instObject", is zero, but...
I forgot that inside of constructor's adapter, "instObject", get again the items created in "onActivityCreated". (sorry)

**Second:**
I thought that might get the item with something like this:

```
item = instObject.getItem(position);  //well I'm newbie!  :P
```

And then, get the content like this:

```
myView.setText(item.getTitle());
```

**Third:**
I overlooked that the method getItem(), had this:

```
@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return instObject.get(position);
}
```

Before getView(), "instObject", had all the items, but then with:

```
MyObject instObject = (MyObject)getItem(position);
```

In technical language, I think that maybe like this:
I make a reference of "instObject", in a specific position.

Without technical...
I create a variable of type object, with the same name, and set only one of all items of "instObject".

**I think I got it, Thanks again!  :)**

Comment: I don't fully understand the problem.   But the "MyObject instObject = (MyObject)getItem(position);"  won't create new object, instead it will return the same object you added earlier.

Comment: @naveejr: it will return the REFERENCE to this object (just as additional info)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what the `getItem()` method inside the adapter does. But generally speaking When you do `getItem()`, the adapter returns the reference to the object at that particular position from a Collection that was passed to the adapter while creating the adapter.

Answer (score 0):

> From what I've learned so far... I'm creating a new instance of MyObject in instObject, so, I think that the value should be zero. But then, when I call setText(...), it work!!! =o

In Java, you create a new object / instance with the `new` operator, as in:

```
Employee employee = new Employee();
```

Your call to `getItem()` is returning a reference to a preexisting object.  Basically, somewhere 'behind the scenes', a new object was already created, and getItem() simply returns a reference to it.  You then store that reference in instObject.